# How to access ActiveStorage tempfile in Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, temporary-files, rails-activestorage, minimagick

I am trying to resize my images before uploading them with Rails' [ActiveStorage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html). The following controller action works like a charm:

```
class CatsController < ApplicationController

  require 'mini_magick'

  def create
    @cat = current_user.cats.new(cat_params)

    params[:cat][:images].each do |image|
      mini_image = MiniMagick::Image.new(image.tempfile.path)
      mini_image.resize '1200x1200'
    end

    if @cat.save
      ...
    end
  end

end
```

But I would like to keep my controllers skinny and move this functionality to the model. But when I do so, Rails can't find `tempfile` in the model.

Is there no way at all to access `tempfile` in the model?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you post yr model method, thats trying to move ?

Comment: I spent hours searching for a way to resize images on upload. This solution finally saved me. It works without any modifications (Rails 6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can create a service

```
# app/services/image_resizer.rb

class ImageResizer
  def self.call(images, size)
    Array(images).each do |image|
      i = MiniMagick::Image.new(image.tempfile.path)
      i.resize size
    end
  end
end
```

```
def create
  @cat = current_user.cats.new(cat_params)
  ImageResizer.call(params[:cat][:images], '1200x1200')

  if @cat.save
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Not perfect but it reduces my controller code to one line. So this is what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Comment: Or you could move the whole `params.each`section to a helper, so in your controller you would just have `my_resize_function(params)`, or so. Just remember to include the helper in the controller.